# How do I generate data for Google Visualizations on the server using WebSharper

Tags: f#, websharper

My goal is to be able to generate data for a Google Visualizations on the server, and then pass it to the client as java script so that it can be rendered as a line chart. My example below compiles correctly, but produces an error when rendered in a browser. What do I need to do to get the DataCommon object to render correctly as java script, after it has been built on the server?

```
namespace Website

open System

type Action =
    | Test

module Page =
    open System.Web
    open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Sitelets
    open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Html

    let Page title body : Content<Action> =       
        PageContent (fun context -> 
            { Page.Default with
                Title = Some(title)
                Body = body context
            })

module Chart =
    open System

    open IntelliFactory.WebSharper
    open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Html
    open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Google
    open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Google.Visualization
    open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Google.Visualization.Base
    open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.EcmaScript

    open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Web

    let RandomData () =

        let random = new Random()

        let valueCount = 100
        let maxValue = 300
        let seriesCount = random.Next(5)

        let data = new Base.DataTable()
        data.addRows(valueCount)
        |> ignore        

        let addSeries index =
            let name = sprintf "Series %d" index
            data.addColumn(ColumnType.NumberType, name)
            |> ignore

            Seq.init valueCount (fun index -> random.Next(maxValue))
            |> Seq.iteri (fun valueIndex value -> data.setValue(index, valueIndex, value) |> ignore)

        [0 .. seriesCount]
        |> List.iter addSeries

        data        

    type LineChart( data : DataCommon, title ) =    
        inherit Web.Control()

        [<JavaScript>]
        override this.Body = 
            let div = 
                Div [] 
                |>! OnAfterRender (fun container ->
                    let visualization = new Visualizations.LineChart(container.Dom)
                    let options = {
                        Visualizations.LineChartOptions.Default with
                            width = 400.0
                            height = 240.0
                            legend = Visualizations.LegendPosition.Bottom
                            title = title
                    }
                    visualization.draw(data, options))
            div :> _

module Site =
    open Chart
    open Page

    open IntelliFactory.Html
    open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Sitelets

    let TestPage =
        Page "Test" (fun (context : Context<Action>) -> 
        [
            Div [Text "Test"]
            Div [new Chart.LineChart(RandomData(), "Test Chart")]
        ])            

    let Main =
        Sitelet.Sum [
            Sitelet.Content "/" Test TestPage
        ]

open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Sitelets
type Website() =    
    interface IWebsite<Action> with
        member this.Sitelet = Site.Main
        member this.Actions = [Test]

[<assembly: WebsiteAttribute(typeof<Website>)>]
do ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RandomData` function runs on the server. You are therefore constructing JavaScript-only `DataTable` objects on the server - the result of doing this is generally undefined.

You should:

1. Mark the server-side function that generates data with `[<Remote>]`.
2. Move UI construction to the client-side code annotated `[<JavaScript>]`.
3. Call the remote function from the client-side - this will use AJAX to get the data. It is good practice to `async.Return` from your remote function so as not to block the browser.

Check the [Remoting](http://websharper.com/samples/Remoting) page or the relevant section of the manual for more information.

Alternatively, you can pass the data to the constructor of your `Control` object and access it from the `Body` member. This will serialize the data during HTML generation and avoid the need for an AJAX call - this is useful for generating static HTML sites, for example.