# Failed to deserialize metadata WebSharper

Tags: f#, google-visualization, f#-3.0, websharper, f#-data

The questions relates to the following link:

[How do I generate data for Google Visualizations on the server using WebSharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963989/how-do-i-generate-data-for-google-visualizations-on-the-server-using-websharper?rq=1)

I wanted to re-implement the above although using the latest version of Websharper (open source alpha release) but I receive the following error:

Failed to deserialize metadata for: IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Google.Visualization, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dcd983dec8f76a71

I opened a Client-Server Web Application; Here is the code for the respective files:

In **Remoting.fs**

```
namespace WebsiteX

open System
open IntelliFactory.WebSharper
open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Html
open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Google
open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Google.Visualization
open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Google.Visualization.Base
open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.EcmaScript
open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Web


module Remoter =
[<Remote>]
let RandomData () =

    let random = new Random()
    let valueCount = 100
    let maxValue = 300
    let seriesCount = random.Next(5)

    let data = new Base.DataTable()
    data.addRows(valueCount)
    |> ignore        

    let addSeries index =
        let name = sprintf "Series %d" index
        data.addColumn(ColumnType.NumberType, name)
        |> ignore

        Seq.init valueCount (fun index -> random.Next(maxValue))
        |> Seq.iteri (fun valueIndex value -> data.setValue(index, valueIndex, value) |> ignore)

    [0 .. seriesCount]
    |> List.iter addSeries

    data
```

In **Client.fs:**

```
namespace WebsiteX

open IntelliFactory.WebSharper
open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Html
open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Google
open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Google.Visualization
open IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Google.Visualization.Base
open Remoting

[<JavaScript>]
module Client =

    [<Remote>]    
    let dd = Remoter.RandomData() 


    [<JavaScript>]
    let Main() =
        Div []
        |>! OnAfterRender(fun container ->
            let visualization = new LineChart(container.Body)
            let options =
                LineChartOptions(
                    width = 400,
                    height = 240,
                    legend = Legend(position = LegendPosition.Bottom),
                    title = "Title")
        visualization.draw(dd, options))
```

I didn't change anything in the Main.fs (it is the same as the provided template). I am not familiar so much with web development, so there might be an easy answer.

Why when I try to build it to I receive the following:
Failed to deserialize metadata for: IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Google.Visualization, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dcd983dec8f76a71

I downloaded Websharper and installed the pre-release versions from Nuget.
Using WebSharper.3.0.1.73-alpha and WebSharper.Google.Visualization.3.0.2.193-alpha

Fixed it by upgrading to WebSharper.3.0.3.76-alpha.. but when I run it in Google Chrome I get the following:

```
You called the draw() method with the wrong type of data rather than a DataTable or DataView
```

Thanks!

Comment: So you ended up with Websharper-3.0.3.76-alpha and visualization.3.02.1930-alpha? That should work. The message does not seem to be related to package versions, but comes from Google Data Visualization javascript library.